# dd - how to extract a subsection of a file with 2 offsets?

Tags: linux, dd

I have a file that I want where the starting byte offset is 3020852 and the ending byte offset is 13973824.

There's some variation of this command: `dd ibs=X obs=Y skip=1 count=1` that I haven't got working yet.

Comment: How about just using a hex editor to cut & paste the section you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help from @agtoever and @tom-yan this is the fastest way to achieve this:

```
dd if=somefile of=somefile2 skip=$start_offset count=$(($end_offset-$start_offset)) iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes
```

I left the `bs` unspecified, but it can be set to anything. A 1MiB bs is a good rule of thumb.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to do this, as you can read in [this similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file). I'll give you the (in my opinion most "idiomatic") `head | tail` approach and the `dd` approach.

`head --bytes=<end_offset> in_file.bin | tail --bytes=<end_offset - start_offset> > out_file.bin`

Alternatively:

`dd bs=1 skip=<start_offset> count=<end_offset - start_offset> < in_file > out_file.bin`

Comment: seek= is for output so it should be skip= instead.

Comment: also the suffix "b" means 512 instead "byte". so bs=1b probably is equivalent to bs=512, which is inappropriate in this case. it should be bs=1c , or simply bs=1 instead; bs= takes the value as byte count anyway.

Comment: iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes instead of bs=1 would probably work too.

Comment: @TomYan thanks for the suggestions. I edited the answer accordingly. I sticked with the bs=1 because it's clearer, more often used and less verbose.

Comment: Problem with using `bs=1` is that it ends up transferring 1 byte at a time, that's kind of slow.

Comment: Perhaps something like this: `dd if=somefile of=somefile2 skip=100 count=100 iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes`

Comment: @CMCDragonkai yeah the performance issue of bs=1 is my concern too. i am not sure if it exists on filesystem level access like on block level access though

Comment: Performance **is** an issue reading/writing per byte. I have no command line available right now. Maybe adding suffixes with skip and count works? So: `dd bs=1M skip=12345c count=67890c if=infile.bin of=outfile.bin` works???

Comment: Anyhow, the dd performance issues also underlines the more obvious choice of head & tail.

Answer (score 1):

Where existing tools fail, write your own:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
start, end = 3020852, 13973824
with open("input.bin", "rb") as inf:
    with open("output.bin", "wb") as outf:
        inf.seek(start)
        data = inf.read(end-start)
        outf.write(data)
        # just in case
        assert(inf.tell() == end)
```

The total size isn't large so it just reads the whole block into RAM at once. If you wanted to copy several GB block-by-block, you could do it this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
start = 3020852
end = 13973824
size = end - start
bs = 32 << 20   # (32 MB)
with open("input.bin", "rb") as inf:
    with open("output.bin", "wb") as outf:
        inf.seek(start)
        while size > 0:
            data = inf.read(min(size, bs))
            outf.write(data)
            size -= len(data)
        assert(inf.tell() == end)
```